# When and Why does Chrome display malware detection warning?

Tags: web-browser, malware, chrome

Google Chrome contains malware detection feature. When user visits some site, browser may display warning that site contains malware.

What does it mean that site contains malware? Does it mean that site contains link to download malware or that site tries to bypass browser's security mechanisms?

How does Chrome detect that site contains malware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Google SafeBrowsing](http://code.google.com/p/google-safe-browsing/wiki/SafeBrowsingDesign). Google keeps a blacklist database of what sites are known or suspected of hosting malware and [provides APIs](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) for browsers to check the list.

> Safe Browsing is a service provided by Google that enables applications to check URLs against Google's constantly updated lists of suspected phishing and malware pages.